# Unexpected token '&' while reading json object as string in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json

I have a model which will read a json object as a string.

```
string zipCodes = "[{'zip': '06854','market_area': 'R01','state': 'CT'}, 
                    {'zip': '06842','market_area': 'R01','state': 'CT'}, 
                    {'zip': '02765','market_area': 'R02','state': 'TN'}]"
```

I am trying to read this string as a constant in javascript.

```
const array = @Model.zipCodes;
```

But the value is returning as

```
const array = [{&#39;zip&#39;: &#39;06854&#39;,&#39;market_area&#39;: 
                &#39;R01&#39;,&#39;state&#39;: &#39;CT&#39;}, 
               {&#39;zip&#39;: &#39;06842&#39;,&#39;market_area&#39;: 
                &#39;R01&#39;,&#39;state&#39;: &#39;CT&#39;}, 
               {&#39;zip&#39;: &#39;02765&#39;,&#39;market_area&#39;: 
                &#39;R02&#39;,&#39;state&#39;: &#39;TN&#39;}];
```

and throwing an unexpected token '&' error.

How can we handle this error.

Thank you.

Comment: for starters: your json isn't valid json. `'` should be `"`.

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. If you replace the single quotes with double quotes, you have an array of objects encoded as JSON string.